# Number of subsequent infections per case / overdispersion of COVID-19

Tags: epidemiology, sars-cov-2, covid-19-datasets

I am aware that SARS-CoV-2 shows overdispersion, that is that many infected people cause no subsequent infections, but a small number of people cause very many infections (superspreading). The best illustration I could find of this is the one below, from [the Economist](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2020/11/07/a-minority-of-people-with-covid-19-account-for-the-bulk-of-transmission) (begid a paywall). The figure shows a histogram of the number of subsequent infections per case, where the x-axis is the percentile. This particular data is from a study from Andhra Pradesh & Tamil Nadu, from March-August 2020.

My question is, does this still reflect the current knowledge? Is there a more recent publication that shows this kind of graph (or an other illustration of dispersion), preferably for Europe?

And finally, how does the picture change with the virus variants, e.g. B.1.1.7 - are there less "non-infecting" people, or are the infecting people causing more cases?

[image]

Comment: The actual study cited there is https://science.sciencemag.org/content/370/6517/691 Reasons to be skeptical of that particular finding is that it relied on contact tracing. If you can't trace/find the contacts, you can (wrongly) conclude they didn't infect anyone.

Comment: Those findings seem consistent with what was observed for SARS (at much smaller scale) though https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7094981/